# How to add a cell in-between each filter output

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a row of dates which I want to transpose and add one empty cell between each output.

What I have:

|  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 Jan | 7 Jan | 14 Jan | 21 Jan |

What I want:

|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 Jan |  | 7 Jan |  | 14 Jan |  | 21 Jan |

Comment: Which version of Excel do you use (it determines which functions you've access to)? How many dates do you have? Do you need to do this once or multiple times? (These determine whether a manual process / formula / macro will work better for you)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your data starts at column A, select column B, then Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>. With your finger still press on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key, select the other columns. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd>. New columns will be inserted.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this macro to do it automatically:

It assumes your data is in row 1, there are no empty columns already present, and it doesn't do any transposing as you didn't really display any in your question.It also works with ActiveSheet so when you run it, make sure the sheet with your data is selected.

```
Sub insertColumns()
    Dim max As Integer
    max = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("1:1"))
    
    For i = 1 To max
        Columns(i * 2).Insert
    Next i
    
End Sub
```